# web api with angularjs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net web api and I develop a spa app using angualrjs and web api. Once on construction I met a situation calling simple http get function through api, api get functions are

```
public class ProductApiController : ApiController
{
    private toolForExamEntities db = new toolForExamEntities();

    // GET api/ProductApi
    [HttpGet]
    public List<tblProduct> GettblProducts()
    {

        return db.tblProducts.ToList();
    }

     [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GettblProducts()
    {

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, db.tblProducts);
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GettblProducts()
    {
        if (db.tblProducts == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(db.tblProducts); 
    }
```

above i have googled three methods, just i want to know about each methods exact uses.
thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like your code is using an Entity Framework DbContext to get data from database and return it back as response.

Comment: Please be a lot more clear about what your problem is, or what exactly it is that you need help with.

Comment: yeah fetching data using entity framework, i need explanation above three methods and which is best to use get response to $http and why